# Distributed TensorFlow: error occurred when assigning ps and worker to the same machine

Tags: tensorflow, distribute

I am running distributed tensorflow on 2 machines: `pc1` and `pc2` following the [inception distributed training tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). I found if I use one machine as ps and the other as worker, it runs well. The scripts are as follows:

```
# run worker on pc2
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=32 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:2222' \
--worker_hosts='pc2:2222'

# run ps on pc1
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--job_name='ps' \
--task_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:2222' \
--worker_hosts='pc2:2222'
```

However, if I run a worker on each machine, i.e. 2 workers in all and run ps on one of those 2 machines, the program crashes. The scripts are as follows:

```
# run worker_1 on pc1
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=32 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2222,pc2:2222'

# run worker_2 on pc2
bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--batch_size=32 \
--data_dir=$HOME/imagenet-data \
--job_name='worker' \
--task_id=1 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc1:2222,pc2:2222'

# run ps on pc1 on port: 3333
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train \
--job_name='ps' \
--task_id=0 \
--ps_hosts='pc1:3333' \
--worker_hosts='pc2:2222'
```

The errors occurred on `worker_1` are as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 260, in train
    sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(target, config=sess_config)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 719, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
    init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 256, in prepare_session
    config=config)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 188, in _restore_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1439, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key total_loss/avg not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1653 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1653/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1653/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: _recv_save/Const_0_S1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=39394642820946720, tensor_name="edge_5065__recv_save/Const_0", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_1653', defined at:
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 233, in train
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1051, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1081, in build
    restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 675, in build
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 402, in _AddRestoreOps
    tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 242, in restore_op
    [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 668, in restore_v2
    dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2395, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1264, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key total_loss/avg not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_1653 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_1653/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_1653/shape_and_slices)]]
     [[Node: _recv_save/Const_0_S1 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=39394642820946720, tensor_name="edge_5065__recv_save/Const_0", tensor_type=DT_STRING, _device="/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I also try to use 1 worker and 1 ps on only one machine on different ports, but the error remains.

So my question is: does that mean ps and worker must be assigned to different machines, even they are assigned to different ports? The reason for using one machine to be worker and ps simultaneously is to maximize the utilization of computing resources. Could anyone show me how to use one machine to be both worker and ps?

Comment: the error happens in checkpoint loading which shouldn't depend on how things are distributed. Could you picking up the wrong checkpoint? To test, try deleting/hiding your checkpoint directory so that it creates new one

Comment: @Yaroslav, yes, that is where the problem lays. It works well now. Thx a lot!